# Кнопка на регистрацию и вход в wordpress без виджета и плагина, какие варианты?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

столкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно поставить кнопки на вход и регистрацию. Если использовать виджет мета , то войдя кнопка регистрации меняется на кнопку управление сайтам , даже если ты не админ. Если есть вариант как это исправить , пожалуйста подскажите. среди плагинов ничего нормального тоже не нашел. Как можно сделать ссылки на вход и регистрацию? Может совет есть или решение готовое? Спасибо

Comment: А что мешает просто поставить ссылки? Правда непонятно зачем ссылка на "вход", если уже залогинен, но дело хозяйское.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно вывести ссылки вот так, добавив этот код в нужное вам место в шаблоне

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url() ) . '">' . __( 'Login' ) . '</a>';
}

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && get_option( 'users_can_register' ) ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_registration_url() ) . '">' . __( 'Register' ) . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: Darth KYL, Я так сделал, но ничего не появилось. Может  что-то нужно в functions прописать?

Comment: я заменил первый if  на такой код, это приветствуется? if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
                    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url() ) . '">' . __( 'Вход' ) . '</a>';
                } else if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
                 echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_logout_url() ) . '">' . __( 'Выход' ) . '</a>';
                }

Comment: Не нужно делать else if, у пользователя может быть два состояния авторизованн и неавторизированн. if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_login_url() ) . '">' . __( 'Вход' ) . '</a>'; } else { echo '<a href="' . esc_url( wp_logout_url() ) . '">' . __( 'Выход' ) . '</a>'; }

Comment: как я понял можно было просто else поставить? Просто я подумал, что с else if вернее будет.